# for loop condition issue

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
int a, b, c;
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = a + 2*b;
for (a=1; c<15; a++)
{               
    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I have a simple question. Do I have to define my condition depending on my initializing variable?
In the example above, I want the loop to stop when a variable "a" becomes 10, so variable "c" will be less than 15.
But the output is infinite lines of "5". I expect my output to be 14.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have to, but you'd need to update the value of `c`

Comment: You are printing always the variable c and you never change c. So the output is 14 time the value of c

Comment: @Meriç the question is not dumb. You have asked a valid question: "do i have to define my condition depending on my initializing variable?". You just did not manage to program your loop in a working manner.

Comment: @Meriç just a reminder since you are a new user, you can accept the best answer which helped you, that gives additional credit to you and the person who answered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted you could omit all 3 parts of a for loop so it essentially becomes a `while(true)` loop

```
for(;;)
```

So no, it doesn't need to.

But to make your program work, you'll need to update the value of c inside the loop

```
    for (a=1; c<15; a++)
    {
        c = a + 2*b;
        Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

move c change inside of the loop, or you will itereate without end:

```
for (a=1; c<15; a++)
{
    c = a + 2*b;
    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> do i have to define my condition depending on my initializing variable?

no you don't you can define any condition you want.

> what am I doing wrong?

You never so something to make this condition `false` it will run forever like in your case.

You change `c` only once before the loop starts:

```
c = a + 2*b;
for (a=1; c<15; a++)
{               
    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
}
```

as soon as you enter the loop `c` is never changed again! Move the changing part into the loop:

```
for (a=1; c<15; a++)
{               
    c = a + 2*b;
    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
}
```

You could even write the loop using a `bool` variable

```
bool condition = true;
for (int a = 0; condition; i++)
{
    c = a + 2*b;
    if (c > 15)
    { 
        condition = false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You could even do the computation inside the comparison block of the for-loop and it would work:

```
for (a = 0; (c = a + 2 * b) < 15; a++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
}
```

Disclaimer: I would not recommend it because it is cryptic and horrible to read.

Answer (score 0):

**A** inside condition:

```
for (a=1; a<=10; a++)
{
    c = a + 2*b;
    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
}
```

Loop will stop when, **c** becomes 14.

Comment: This completely changes when the loop should stop

Comment: @Sayse, Edited answer, now it will give desired output

Comment: It only gives the desired answer for the current equation for `c`, I wouldn't call that reliable.

Comment: the value `10` is base on the value of `b`. If `b` should ever change then the `10` will not fit anymore

Comment: actually i only need the final value.

Comment: @Meriç Then: what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve here? the last integer before 15 is 14. That would be you final value ;)

Comment: i didn't want first 14 output on console, and I just solved it by taking Console.WriteLine(c.ToString()); line out of the loop. I have another question with [iterator] part but i'm not sure if i ask it in here or post another question? what do you think?

Comment: @Meriç if it is a different question, you should make a new post